# Is "UseCompressedOops" enabled by default in Jdk 8

Tags: java, jvm, java-8

I recently read about the -XX:+UseCompressedOops JVM option that allows to negate the overhead imposed by 64 bit JVM by storing compressed 64 bit Ordinary object pointers (aka OOPS).

It looks like it is recommended that we should always use this flag. So I was wondering if its being enabled by default in the recently released Jdk 8 ?

Comment: According to [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.be/2012/06/what-is-xxusecompressedoops-in-64-bit.html) it has been enabled by default in Java 6 Update 18:  although [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/10019916) states it is only in 6u23. This would indicate it is still enabled by default since I didn't find any evidence to the contrary.

Comment: `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` is ON by default in JDK8 when Java heap sizes are less than 32 GB.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, knowbody Thanks a lot.. After upgrading my dev environment to Java 8 64 bit JVM I was experiencing high memory usage, started wondering if I can do anything about it and came across this JVM flag.